# How can I force IPython to only give me a new prompt when all threads have finished

Tags: python, multithreading, ipython

I'm using IPython to develop a multi-threaded socket based client-server type thing. The problem is IPython tries to give it's command prompt prompt before some of my threads have finished running. The debug text output of the thread is then lost.

Is there any way to have IPython only give me a new prompt when all the threads have finished running?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
threads = [threading.Thread(target=myFunc) for i in range(n)]
for t in threads:
    t.start()
...
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

where `threads` is a list of your `threading.Thread` instances. This will cause the main thread to wait until all worker threads are done.

Comment: Would I have to explicitly add my threads to this list as I create them? I start each thread using Thread(target=myFunc) rather than extending the Thread class.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to build `threads` as you create them. I edited my post to show one way.

Comment: Okay great, thanks. I haven't been able to test this as I think to use it I will have to do some code restructuring. I haven't used threads before so I think it's a bit of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting for the thread to finish, you could instead send debugging output to some sort of buffer, and then arrange for IPython to print the content of this buffer each time it prints a prompt.  To see more debugging output, you enter a blank line to get IPython to flush the buffer to the console:

```
def ipython_logging():
    import logging.handlers
    # setup a logging handler to actually print output to the console
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(logging.BASIC_FORMAT))
    console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # then setup a handler that buffers the output.  the float('inf')'s suppress automatic flushing.
    memory = logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(capacity=float('inf'),
                                            flushLevel=float('inf'),
                                            target=console)
    memory.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.root.addHandler(memory)
    logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # tell IPython to flush the buffer every time it prints a prompt.
    import IPython
    def flush_log(self, *args, **kwargs):
        memory.flush()
        raise IPython.ipapi.TryNext
    ip = IPython.ipapi.get()
    ip.set_hook("generate_prompt", flush_log)
```

So you can then do logging from your thread:

```
import logging
import threading
import time
import random

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadnum):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.__threadnum = threadnum
    def run(self):
        freq = random.randrange(1,10)
        count = random.randrange(20)
        for i in range(count):
            time.sleep(freq)
            LOGGER.debug("output from #%d, i=%d, freq=%d", self.__threadnum, i, freq)
```

which, when used, might look a bit like this:

```
$ ipython 
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Apr 12 2011, 16:15:16) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.10.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import soithreads

In [2]: soithreads.ipython_logging()

In [3]: [soithreads.MyThread(n).start() for n in range(3)]
Out[3]: [None, None, None]

In [4]: 

In [5]: 

In [6]: 

In [7]: 
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #1, i=0, freq=3

In [8]: 

In [9]: 
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #1, i=1, freq=3

In [10]: 

In [11]: 

In [12]: 

In [13]: 
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #2, i=0, freq=8

In [14]: 

In [15]: 
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #1, i=2, freq=3
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #0, i=0, freq=9

In [16]: 

In [17]: 
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #1, i=3, freq=3

In [18]: 

In [19]: 

In [20]: 

In [21]: 

In [22]: 

In [23]: 
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #1, i=4, freq=3

In [24]: 

In [25]: 
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #2, i=1, freq=8

In [26]: 

In [27]: 

In [28]: 

In [29]: 
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #1, i=5, freq=3
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #0, i=1, freq=9

In [30]: 

In [31]: 

In [32]: 

In [33]: 

In [34]: 

In [35]: 
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #2, i=2, freq=8
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #0, i=2, freq=9
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #2, i=3, freq=8
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #0, i=3, freq=9
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #2, i=4, freq=8
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #0, i=4, freq=9
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #0, i=5, freq=9
DEBUG:soithreads:output from #0, i=6, freq=9

In [36]:
```